# Right side of Robot does not render until manipulated WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, model, webgl, hierarchy

I am learning WebGL model hierarchies and wrote a program to draw a robot with independently movable arm segments that are connected to the torso. I was able to accomplish this, with the side effect that the right upper and lower arms will not render until manipulated via slider.

Things I have tried:

Declaring separate variables for both left and right arms, no effect.
Making a copy of the modelViewMatrix instead of push/popping from a stack, no effect.
Broke down the drawrobot function to render separate heirarchies (arms) in the render function directly, no effect.
Checked for typos, nothing found.

I'm really going crazy trying to locate my problem. Help/Ideas appreciated, code is below:

```html
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main() 
{
    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying  vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{ 
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myrobotArm.js"></script>

<div id="slider1">
body angle -180 <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
  />
 180
</div><br/>

<div id="slider2">
lower leftarm angle -180 <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
  />
 180
</div><br/>

<div id="slider3">
upper leftarm angle -180 <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
  />
 180
</div><br/>

<div id="slider4">
lower rightarm angle -180 <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
  />
 180
</div><br/>

<div id="slider5">
upper rightarm angle -180 <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
  />
 180
</div><br/>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512"
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var NumVertices = 36; //(6 faces)(2 triangles/face)(3 vertices/triangle)

var points = [];
var colors = [];
var myStack = [];


var vertices = [
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
];

// RGBA colors
var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
];


// Parameters controlling the size of the Robot's arm

var BASE_HEIGHT      = 5.0;
var BASE_WIDTH       = 2.0;
var LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT = 0.5;
var LOWER_ARM_WIDTH  = 2.0;
var UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT = 0.5;
var UPPER_ARM_WIDTH  = 2.0;

var LOWERR_ARM_HEIGHT = 0.5;
var LOWERR_ARM_WIDTH  = 2.0;
var UPPERR_ARM_HEIGHT = 0.5;
var UPPERR_ARM_WIDTH  = 2.0;

// Shader transformation matrices

var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;

// Array of rotation angles (in degrees) for each rotation axis

var Base = 0;
var LowerArmL = 1;
var UpperArmL = 2;
var LowerArmR = 3;
var UpperArmR = 4;

var theta= [ 0, 0, 0];

var angle = 0;

var modelViewMatrixLoc;

var vBuffer, cBuffer;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function quad(  a,  b,  c,  d ) {
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[a]); 
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[b]); 
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[c]);
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[a]); 
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[c]); 
    colors.push(vertexColors[a]); 
    points.push(vertices[d]); 
}


function colorCube() {
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

//____________________________________________

// Remmove when scale in MV.js supports scale matrices

function scale4(a, b, c) {
   var result = mat4();
   result[0][0] = a;
   result[1][1] = b;
   result[2][2] = c;
   return result;
}


//--------------------------------------------------


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }
    
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST ); 
    
    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();
    
    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );    
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Create and initialize  buffer objects
    
    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    document.getElementById("slider1").onchange = function(event) {
        theta[0] = event.target.value/2;
    };
    document.getElementById("slider2").onchange = function(event) {
         theta[1] = event.target.value/2;
    };
    document.getElementById("slider3").onchange = function(event) {
         theta[2] = event.target.value/2;
    };
    document.getElementById("slider4").onchange = function(event) {
         theta[3] = event.target.value/2;
    };
    document.getElementById("slider5").onchange = function(event) {
         theta[4] = event.target.value/2;
    };

    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");

    projectionMatrix = ortho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix"),  false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );
    
    render();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function base() {
    var s = scale4(BASE_WIDTH, BASE_HEIGHT, BASE_WIDTH);
    var instanceMatrix = mult( translate( 0.0, 0.5 * BASE_HEIGHT, 0.0), s);
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function upperArmL() {
    var s = scale4(UPPER_ARM_WIDTH, UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT, UPPER_ARM_WIDTH);
    var instanceMatrix = mult(translate( -0.5 * UPPER_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0),s);    
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function lowerArmL()
{
    var s = scale4(LOWER_ARM_WIDTH, LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT, LOWER_ARM_WIDTH);
    var instanceMatrix = mult(translate(-0.5 * LOWER_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0),s);
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

function upperArmR() {
    var s = scale4(UPPERR_ARM_WIDTH, UPPERR_ARM_HEIGHT, UPPERR_ARM_WIDTH);
    var instanceMatrix = mult(translate(0.5 * UPPERR_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0),s);    
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function lowerArmR()
{
    var s = scale4(LOWERR_ARM_WIDTH, LOWERR_ARM_HEIGHT, LOWERR_ARM_WIDTH);
    var instanceMatrix = mult(translate( 0.5 * LOWERR_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0),s);
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function drawRobot()
{
     modelViewMatrix = rotate(theta[Base], 0, 1, 0 );
     var myMVM = modelViewMatrix;
   //  myStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
     base();
 
   // modelViewMatrix = myStack.pop();
   // modelViewMatrix = myMVM;
   // myStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
    modelViewMatrix  = mult(modelViewMatrix, translate(-0.5 * BASE_WIDTH, BASE_HEIGHT - 0.5 * UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT, 0.0));  //POSITION OF RECT
    modelViewMatrix  = mult(modelViewMatrix, rotate(theta[UpperArmL], 0, 0, 1));   //ROTATE AROUND Z AXIS BY UPPERARML Degrees
    upperArmL();

    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, translate(-UPPER_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0)); 
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, rotate(theta[LowerArmL], 0, 0, 1));
    lowerArmL();

   // modelViewMatrix =  myStack.pop();
    modelViewMatrix = myMVM;
    modelViewMatrix  = mult(modelViewMatrix, translate(0.5 * BASE_WIDTH, BASE_HEIGHT - 0.5 * UPPERR_ARM_HEIGHT, 0.0));
    modelViewMatrix  = mult(modelViewMatrix, rotate(theta[UpperArmR], 0, 0, 1));
    upperArmR();

    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, translate(UPPERR_ARM_WIDTH, 0.0, 0.0)); 
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, rotate(theta[LowerArmR], 0, 0, 1));
    lowerArmR();
}

var render = function() {

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    drawRobot();
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

Comment: The information in your first paragraph was irrelevant, so I removed it. It would probably help you to get answers faster if you provided more details than *The code runs without errors and works as intended* regarding the code you've posted.

Comment: I appreciate the response. The method used in my book says to push the matrix I want to use as a parent to a stack, then pop/push it back on before doing each child branch transformation, which preserves the initial modelViewMatrix (torso) transformation for each inherited child to use. this allows arm segments to be added by only calling the pop/push after the whole arm is drawn, which connects them to each other for natural joint movement. I tried this approach and it gives me the same result as my current "create a var and set it to the matrix I want preserved".  So it's passing properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments, and my answere will probably be rejectect since it don't directily resolve your problem, but I say what I think, because many people have similar problems than you for the exactly same reason: An unadapted approach of objects transformation hierarchy management.

As you noticed yourself, it is hard to know exactly where your problem come from, but since you say that manipulating sliders (so, force updating data) makes things to "appear", there is high probability that your problem is related to wrong values at initial state. Anyway, the way your program manage transformation matrices don't make things easy to debug and control, you will have hard time to tune that, this is because you don't use the good approach.

Unfortunately, almost no books nor tuturial give the correct way to manage transformation hierarchy. Instead, they give examples using this old pop / push matrix approach, because this is adapted to imperative programmation style, and quick to write. The good approache would requiere an entire chapter.

The transformation hierarchy principle is pretty simple: each object's "final matrix" is the result of the accumulated transformation of all its parents plus its own transformation. The proper way to manage transformation hierarchy is to reflect the logical structure of the hierarchy in your program structure, that is, by working with objects, so to say, to think in Object−Oriented programation paradigm.

To properly manage this, you have to create a Graph with nodes, where each node have parent and children, so to say: a Scene structure. Here is the fundamental object you need to implement:

```
function Node() {
  this.parent = null;
  this.childs = new Array();
  this.matrix = new Float32Array(16);
  this.worldMatrix = new Float32Array(16);

  setIdentity(this.matrix);
  setIdentity(this.worldMatrix);
}

MyNode.prototype = {

  setParent(parent) {
     // very simple parenting management
     this.parent = parent;
     parent.childs.psuh(this);
  },

  updateMatrix() {
    // recursive matrix update (other methods are possible)
    if(this.parent) {
      this.parent.updateMatrix();
      this.worldMatrix = multiply(this.matrix, this.parent.worldMatrix);
    } else {
      this.worldMatrix = this.matrix;
    }
  },
}
```

And here is how to use this:

```
let torso = new Node();

let upperArmR = new Node();
upperArmR.setParent(torso);

let lowerArmR = new Node();
lowerArmR.setParent(upperArmR);

let upperArmL = new Node();
upperArmL.setParent(torso);

let lowerArmL = new Node();
lowerArmL.setParent(upperArmL);
```

Once you have this, you have a hierarchical structure you can explores since each object have an identified parent, and children. You can control the local transformation of each object by its local matrix, update all hierarchy, and use the final world matrix to draw, like this:

```
// this is pseudocode..
rotate(upperArmR.matrix, upperArmRRotation);
rotate(lowerArmR.matrix, lowerArmRRotation);

upperArmR.updateMatrix();
lowerArmR.updateMatrix();

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, upperArmR.worldMatrix);
// draw
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, lowerArmR.worldMatrix);
// draw
```

Now, you have fine control on your scene hierarchy and transformation, you can debug each matrix independently to catch wrong transformation, and you can animate all this in easy way.

However notice that in my example, I use a recursive function to always recompute all matrices of the whole hierarchy tree, this induce waste of calculation, since in this case, for each children matrix update, the parent matrix will be recomputed again. To prevent that, you have several solution. One is to add a flag in your node to tell that the matrix is up to date and don't need to be recalculated until the next general update. Another is to do not use a recursive call, but to explores your graph in depth-first to update each node in the proper hierarchy order. I let you explore google using "Depth-First Traversal" or "Depth-First Search" as key words to found methods to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for a very informative post. I was aware of the tree-based approach as it is covered in my textbook. However, my instructor only covered the stack version in class. So when I developed my code, I tried that method. When I asked him why it wasn't working, he told me he had to make a copy of the base matrix and use that for each arm set to get his version to work, which is why I tried that method instead. I have some time this weekend, so I'll rebuild with the tree approach and see if I can find my bug.

Comment: Using matrices's stacks for transformation hierarchy is not practicable in real projects, this quickly become hell. Even with only three or four objects, this becomes hard to manage between push and pop, you probably noticed that yourself. Creating smart tree structure will take some time, but once done, your are free to complexify your scene as much as you want.